# Is UK passport valid period after leaving zone defined by issue date for Schengen zone (France)?

Tags: schengen, passports, uk-citizens

### Background

Before October 2018 in the UK it was possible to have a passport issue that was valid for longer than 10 years. When your passport was renewed some remaining time from your previous passport could extend the validity period beyond 10 years. The Schengen countries don't recognise this extension for entry to the zone.

According to the [UK Government website](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/france/entry-requirements), to enter France you passport needs to meet these two critera:

1. Issued less than 10 years before the date you enter the country (check the ‘date of issue’)
2. Valid for at least 3 months after the day you plan to leave (check the ‘expiry date’)

I know that [people have been refused entry](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-scotland-61312855) for using a passport issued more than 10 years ago.

### My question

I am not certain what the 'valid' date in the second criteria refers to. It could mean:

1. The expiry date printed in the passport, say 1 November 2022.
2. Ten years from the date of issue, say 1 October 2022.

If the date three months after I plan to leave the Schengen zone is 15 October 2022, will I be allowed to enter?

Comment: As you have seen from the news, even if the European Commission has clairified the rules, some border guards and airlines agents may still have a problem with passport with extended validity.

Answer (score 1):

The second condition assume that you fullfill the first one. Most rules are written as to be interpreted as a it's logical `AND` (i.e. you fail either or all, then you fail the whole passport validity requirements)

(From Timatic, database for documentation requirements)

> Passports and/or passport replacing documents issued more than 10 years prior to date of travel are not accepted.

`AND`

> Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be valid for a minimum of 3 months beyond the period of intended stay.

This is further stated by [Citizen Advice](https://www.citizensadvice.org.uk/consumer/holiday-cancellations-and-compensation/travelling-in-europe/)

> You’ll need to renew your passport if either:

> There’s less than 3 months left on your passport when you travel

> your passport is 10 years old or more the day after you leave the country - count this from the date your passport was issued

---

With the dates stated, you are abiding to the rules for entry into France

Comment: I do see your point and understand the logical ```and```. I suppose my question hinges on the word 'valid' in the second point. Do they see a passport as being 'valid' only up to 10 years from issue or will they accept the expiry date printed in the passport?

Comment: The European Commission [said](https://www.independent.co.uk/travel/news-and-advice/easyjet-brexit-passport-expire-passenger-flight-b1957496.html) (taken from this [answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/173622/118049)) that it only *cared* about the 10-years limit on entry, and it fits with all the guidelines from the FCO, Timatic and others @Mehmet