How uncommon/problematic is a passport whose validity period (period between issue and expiry) is a non-whole number of years?
I was issued, due to certain administrative reasons in my country (which apply in relatively few cases for my country) a passport where the expiry date is a non-whole number of years after the issue date.
So (putting aside the year, which is generally different) the date of expiry is completely different from the issue date. So it is something like 24/02/2024 to 05/01/2027.
I have never seen this, and I found very few examples online of this happening. So, I am worried this would give me issues with travel due to looking like the passport is erroneous or something.
So my question is whether this is truly as uncommon as I think, and whether it is likely to lead to problems.

On passport you see issuing date and expiring date. I do not remember about validity period, so I really assume it doesn't matter. And it is very common in non-ordinary passport (temporary, service, diplomatic)

By validity period I meant the difference/period between the expiry date and issue date. It doesn't appear explicitly, I just meant it can easily be seen that the expiry date is completely different from the issue date.

Do you know why the dates are different? I'm not asking you to post the reason here, but it might be helpful to have an answer if you are being questioned by someone checking your documents.

Yeah, but because it is not explicit written, i doubt it matter. For me, it stand out the short period not the length of the period.

In my case, I got a passport like this because they found a mistake in the passport (fingerprints for left/right hands swapped) and offered to issue a passport with the fingerprints fixed. The new passport didn't allow me to change the picture (so not a free renewal), and got the same expiry date. I haven't had issues traveling with it.

As each country independently decides who can and can't get in, and that this is a rare-ish situation, my gut feeling is that this question is too broad to answer.

I have filled out so many passport-related forms. They all ask for the expiry date. I don't recall ever being asked for the validity date or the term of the passport.

@KateGregory the date of issue is asked for on (e.g.) the Schengen visa form, although the only relevant problem I know of is with passports valid longer than 10 years.

@KateGregory I tested this aspect when doing a mock application for an ESTA this morning, and they asked for both dates.

@PeterM I doubt any country has an explicit policy that would require passports to be issued for some whole number of years, so it's even less predictable situation than your comment implies: if the passport does cause problems, it will be because an officer saw the dates as cause for further investigation.  So the number of independent outcomes is orders of magnitude higher.

Hungary My passport ends on my birthday, seemingly unrelated to the issuance date. Weird birthday present but I figure it must be common for our passports.

Well, I still have one of the old UK passports, from the days when they could have up to six months' validity "credited" from an earlier passport that was being renewed before it had expired, so mine's valid for 10 years 6 months.
I know this is going to be a problem for EU travel once it hits ten years old, but for the past nine years I've had no problems from the non-integer number of years total validity.

Not just EU travel, many countries limit acknowledged passport validity to 10 years.


my question is whether this is truly as uncommon as I think

It's probably fairly uncommon, but, as the other answer shows, not extremely rare.  There are hundreds of countries with various "administrative reasons" that could lead to this.

and whether it is likely to lead to problems.

Problems are highly unlikely.  In the unlikely event that some official does notice and call attention to it, you can always explain whatever administrative quirk it was that led to this situation.

As previously mentioned: before the UK left the EU, if you renewed your UK passport before it expired, they would add the unexpired period to the new passport.
I've had at least 2 passports where this was the case and I've never had any problems in travelling to the USA, EU, Gambia and other places.

@DaveL for the record, this can cause problems now. Now that we've left the EU, the validity period requirements for your passport count until it is 10 years old, rather than up until the expiration date listed on it. As such, if your passport is more than 9 years and 9 months old, but has more than 3 months' before its printed expiration date you could be denied entry. See my previous question (the situation has also been clarified in the years since) https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/172170/was-i-incorrectly-denied-boarding-due-to-passport-extensions

@Triatan the rule is that the passport must have been issued more than 10 years before entering.  It is not necessary to leave the Schengen area before the tenth anniversary of the issue date.  If your passport was issued on September 21st 2014, you can enter today as long as you plan to leave at least three months before it expires.  If it's valid for six months, you can enter for up to 90 days.  EU guidance is very clear on this.

@Tristan conversely, anyone can be denied entry with a passport that is valid for more than three months, regardless of when it was issued, if (1) the passport is valid for less than six months, and (2) the intended date of departure is less than three months before the passport's expiration.

huh, yes, it looks like things are now clarified in that favour. In that case I should have been allowed into Norway after all! Oh well

@Tristan indeed, Ryanair got it wrong.  Did you apply for denied boarding compensation?

I did not, and seeing as that was a few years ago, plus at the time the advice was ambiguous (with the advice differing for different schengen member countries), so I doubt it's still available, and probably not worth the hassle of pursuing at this point even if it is

@phoog ITYM "the passport must have been issued fewer than 10 years before entering" - but generally, an excellent clarification, for which I (for one) am grateful.

@MadHatter yes,less than, of course.


my question is whether this is truly as uncommon as I think

While probably it's not very common, right now in Hungary people are almost guaranteed to get such passport. A few years ago a new policy was introduced to have all kind of personal identification documents expire on your birthday. This includes passport, ID card, driving license, and presumably a number of more obscure ones.
My pervious passport expired in a December, but I was born in August, so my current passport has a validity period of 9 years and 8 months.

It won’t be a problem unless the date of expiry is more than ten years after the date of issue, in which case you should treat it as expiring ten years from the date of issue and renew it accordingly.

AFAIK this only applies to the EU, not necessarily other places.
There are also other rules to be aware of for travel to the EU, like it has to be valid for three months from the final day of your stay.

In Turkey, one pays for passport validity time (right now: ~205EUR for 10 years) and the document issuance (~21EUR) separately, and one can always pay just the latter fee to get a new passport with same expiry date as the last one.
I have done this in the past when I changed my name and needed a new passport to reflect that, but it can also be useful if one fills or damages a passport considering how expensive the fee of a 10 year validity currently is.
So, my primary passport right now has ~9.5 years between issuance and expiry, and I traveled quite a bit with it so far. It's treated always as completely normal, no one ever bats an eye or asks questions about it, no system ever causes issues with it and all relevant forms have separate fields for issuance and expiry. You'll be fine, it may be unusual for this to be issued by some countries, but it is not so rare globally.

I would expect some substantial change to be planned for the time close to the end of the document validity.
It is not erorneous, it is just uncommon for one country. Globally I don't think it is that uncommon.
My first licence was issued with unlimitted validity (the valid till window was crossed out) it turned out couple of years the driving licences changed their format entirely - from paper-in-foils to plastic card. At the critical time all channels (TV, radio, newspapers,...) issued how teh change was scheduled and what batches were to be replaced. The whole chage took two years I think and at the time I was issued my licence they didn't know yet the precise schedule.
It might be your passports will be substantially redesigned round 2027 so they are narrowing down the window of coexistence of old designs and new ones. I suppose all relevant offices were, or are about to be, given appropriate informations about the change.
